# ActionView::MissingTemplate in Users#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting a `ActionView::MissingTemplate in Users#show` error in my app.

I have the following code, which renders a partial (html section that is repeated across multiple pages) called `_meta.html.erb`.  This file is in `app/views/users/_meta.html.erb` and contains the following code:

```
<%= image_tag("user_pic.png", alt: @user.name, :class => "profile_pic" ) %>
</br>
<h2 class="user_profile"><%= @user.name %>&nbsp;<%= @user.surname %></h2>
<h3 class="user_location"><%= @user.city %>,&nbsp;<%= @user.state %></h3>
...
```

My `users#show` code as the following:

```
<div id="leftbar">
  <%= render '_meta' %>
</div>
```

I have tried `<%= render '/_meta' %>`, `<%= render 'users/_meta' %>`, `<%= render '/users/_meta' %>`, etc. but nothing seems to be working.

This is probably a Noob error, but I'm stuck.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `render 'meta'`. You don't need to add `_` to the partial name. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) is a guide about rendering in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you render a partial:

```
<%= render partial: 'meta' %>
```

[Partials documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)